# Qiskit histogram to Seaborn

Tags: qiskit, programming

I am running certain circuits in the Aer simulators and I need to present them nicely. I prefer to use the options provided by Seaborn. How can I transfer my Aer data, e.g. histograms, to Seaborn?

For example, running the simple circuit:

```
meas = QuantumCircuit(3, 3)
meas.barrier(range(3))
 
meas.measure(range(3), range(3))


circ.add_register(meas.cregs[0])
qc = circ.compose(meas)

qc.draw()
```

and using Aer

```
backend_sim = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
job_sim = backend_sim.run(transpile(qc, backend_sim), shots=1024)
result_sim = job_sim.result()
counts = result_sim.get_counts(qc)
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram
plot_histogram(counts)
```

yields:

[image]

However, I prefer to use the stylistic options of [Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) instead in order to make nice plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `counts` variable in your code example is just a dictionary with bit strings for keys and the count of times that bit string was returned from the execution of the circuit. Something like: `{"000": 513, "111": 467}`. If you want to make your own plot with seaborn you can just access the data from the [`Counts`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.result.Counts.html?highlight=counts#qiskit.result.Counts) object directly. For example, something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn

counts = {"000": 513, "111": 467}
seaborn.barplot(list(counts.keys()), list(counts.values()))
```

yields:

[image: seaborn bar chart]

That being said `plot_histogram` function does have some style arguments including for color: https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.visualization.plot_histogram.html that may enable you to get the output visualization you want from the function.